# Why does SwiftUI View background extend into safe area?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Here's a view that navigates to a 2nd view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                SecondView()
            } label: {
                Text("Go to 2nd view")
            }
        }
        
    }
}


 struct SecondView: View {
     var body: some View {
         ZStack {
             Color.red
             VStack {
                 Text("This is a test")
                     .background(.green)
                 //Spacer() // <--If you add this, it pushes the Text to the top, but its background no longer respects the safe area--why is this?
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

On the 2nd screen, the green background of the `Text` view only extends to its border, which makes sense because the Text is a pull-in view:

[image]

Now, if you add `Spacer()` after the `Text()`, the `Text` view pushes to the top of the `VStack`, which makes sense, but why does its green background suddenly push into the safe area?

In the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/adding-a-background-to-your-view), it says:

> By default, SwiftUI sizes and positions views to avoid system defined
> safe areas to ensure that system content or the edges of the device
> won’t obstruct your views. If your design calls for the background to
> extend to the screen edges, use the ignoresSafeArea(_:edges:) modifier
> to override the default.

However, in this case, I'm not using `ignoresSafeArea`, so why is it acting as if I did, rather than perform the default like Apple says, which is to avoid the safe areas?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You think that you use [old background modifier version](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/background(_:alignment:)).
But actually, the above code uses a new one, [introduced in iOS 15 version of background modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:)) which by default ignores all safe area edges:

```
func background<S>(_ style: S, ignoresSafeAreaEdges edges: Edge.Set = .all) -> some View where S : ShapeStyle
```

To fix the issue just replace `.background(.green)` with `.background(Color.green)` if your app deployment target < iOS 15.0, otherwise use [a new modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(alignment:content:)): `.background { Color.green }`.

Comment: So smart! Thank you, this is absolutely fantastic. I just learned something new here.

Comment: What the heck?!

Comment: You can also do background(.green, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: .bottom)